# Dijkstra variant with k nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, path, dijkstra

I have to find a min path from a source and destination where source and destination are the same node and I want a minimum fixed number of nodes in the path.
I thought to implement a Dijkstra algorithm (in Java) with the variant that k nodes are included into the minimum path. (k is a minimum number of nodes to cover).
It's correct? If yes, any suggestion for the implementation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A problem is that the start node is marked when you start. You have to unmark it

Comment: yes! Any ideas about implementation for the k nodes?

Comment: This is at least as hard as solving the NP-hard Hamiltonian Cycle problem, since you could solve that problem simply by picking any vertex as the source/destination vertex, setting k=n, and then running your algorithm.

Comment: In a *path*, no vertex can appear more than once.  Is that really what you want?  If so, xenteros's answer is solving a different problem (it counts *walks*, where repeated vertices and edges are allowed), and you're out of luck as the problem is NP-hard as I explained above.  If instead you allow repeated vertices and edges, then you want to count *walks* -- so please edit.  (Or, maybe you want to count *trails*, where vertices but not edges can be repeated.)

Comment: The vertex can't repeat in the path because after I visited I mark it, instead the edges are allowed to repeated. So I think the xenteros's solution works if I make this variant in the algorithm. what do u think?

Comment: If you forbid repeated vertices, then you also forbid repeated edges, since if some edge (u, v) occurs twice then the vertex u (and v) must also appear twice!

Comment: This can also be solved using the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Just set the outer for loop to run up to `k` vertices instead of the `No. of vertices -1` times. That way you will get the shortest path between two paths having at most `k` edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea. Remember to set distance to source to INF instead of 0 at the beginning for correct result.

**EDIT**

> A simple solution is to start from u, go to all adjacent vertices and recur for adjacent vertices with k as k-1, source as adjacent vertex and destination as v. Following is C++ implementation of this simple solution.
>   [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-exactly-k-edges-directed-weighted-graph/)

Comment: thank you for your reply.why set to INF? and how can i pass the k nodes to algorithm?

Comment: there is an implementation under the posted URL

Comment: @Denise feel free to put uparrow and accepted answer next to my answer :)

Comment: The linked algorithm considers *walks*, where vertices (and edges) are allowed to repeat.  The OP asks for *paths*, where vertices (and, therefore, edges) are not allowed to repeat.  (It may be that the OP is confused about what s/he wants, but -1 at least until you clarify which problem the linked algorithm solves.)

Comment: if you flag visited verticles and disallow using them, this will become appropriate algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately the DP no longer works in polynomial time if you do this, because you need to record the *set* of visited vertices as part of the DP state, and there are O(2^n) possible such sets.  The non-DP algorithm still works of course, but it's also exponential-time.